# setBackgroundColor is working in a batch after runtime in google apps script while it should work in runtime

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a code like this:

```
var startingMonthCell = sheet.getRange("D" + currentRow);

for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++){
try{
  //update a firestore DB with some value from spreadsheet cell here
  startingMonthCell.setBackgroundColor("green").setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null);
  startingMonthCell = startingMonthCell.offset(0, 1);
}
catch(e){
  console.log(e);
  startingMonthCell.setBackgroundColor("red").setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null);
  startingMonthCell = startingMonthCell.offset(0, 1);
}
}
```

now expected output is that on every every cell the color will change depending on if the firebase update was successful or not, however what happens is that after the code execution is finished all the cells get updated in batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) after `setBackgroundColor`